# How do I create cascading/dynamic select lists with backbone

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I am attempting to create a reusable backbone view that represents a select element, and supports the following:

- Setting a selected value from a model
- Binding other select views to it, so that when its value changes, other select views update their collections

I've seen a few different resources on this, such as

- http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/07/25/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js/
- http://railsindirection.blogspot.com/2011/08/backbonejs-and-dependent-selects.html

However neither of them seems to support a generalized object that fulfills both purposes - they seem to be hackish.

Does anyone have any advice on how to go about creating this? Or maybe a link to someone else's code that solves this problem elegantly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to implement event aggreator this way.
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/category/backbone-eventbinder/

so you bind the change event on your select list inside the first view to a method that triggres the update in the other views.

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems to be an empty link.

Comment: here is the new one http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/